# React js: mouse cursor always at end of input element when edit text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I use a input element in my React app. In the app I try to use Flux architecture. So when I changed input, I immediately sync the text to my `Store` in `onChange` handler. Then the Store trigger an event to the subscriber which is the app itself to pull the data from the `Store`.

I use `Pub-sub js` to achieve the event mechanism, here is my code:

```
var MyStore = function MyStore() {
    var _this = this;

    this.update = function (name, value) {
        _this.info[name] = value;
        PubSub.publish('STORE_UPDATE');
    };

    this.set = function (obj) {
        _this.info = obj;
    };

    this.get = function () {
        return _this.info;
    };

    this.info = null;
};

var myStore = new MyStore();

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            info: {
                width: '1230000'
            }
        }

        myStore.set({
            width: '1230000'
        })

        PubSub.subscribe('STORE_UPDATE', () => {
            this.setState({
                info: myStore.get()
            })
        })

    }
    onChange (e) {
      myStore.update('width', e.target.value);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="ui form">
                <input value={this.state.info.width} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And here is [Demo on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/52155/)

I want to know why this happened, and how can I fix this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late but this bug related to asynchronous update bug in react. (only happen in Chrome).
The dirty fix I can found is set state of the component before send dispatch it to the store. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/68244/

```
onChange (e) {
  this.setState({info: {
     width: e.target.value
  }});
  myStore.update('width', e.target.value);
}
```